# Run-time error 1004 in Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that I use to create invoices and a macro used to save the workbook to a new file and cleared contents etc ready for the next invoice input.

Since upgrading to Windows 10 and MS Office 365 the macro has stopped working. I am far from an expert, I cobbled together several bits from the net and managed to create a macro that worked - before the upgrade!

I am getting a Run-time error "1004" Method 'Save As" of object '_workbook' failed.

The macro is

```
Sub NextInvoice()

    Range("D3").Value = Range("D3").Value + 1
    Range("B18:H43").ClearContents

End Sub

Sub SaveInvoiceNewName()

    Dim NewFN As Variant

    'Copy invoice to a new workbook

    ActiveSheet.Copy

    NewFN = "C:\This PC\Documents\Brewing\Invoices\Invoice " & Range("C5").Value & Range("D3").Value & ".xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFN, FileFormat:=xlOpenXLSMWorkbookMacroEnabled

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    NextInvoice
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `xlOpenXLSMWorkbookMacroEnabled`. I believe you meant `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`.

```
'let the FileFormat add the appropriate file extension.
NewFN = "C:\This PC\Documents\Brewing\Invoices\Invoice " & Range("C5").Value & Range("D3").Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFN, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

See [xlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx).